# How to load a full library with css and js to html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say i wrote some local library that contains `js` and `css` files (no html).
This library has a `js` file with a `class` that get a DOM `id` as argument and load all `css` into that element independently.

I would like "share" that library, or just include it in my `html` page.

The only way I know currently, is to load each file from this folder separately like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/lib/style.css"/>
<script src="lib/main.js"></script>
```

and so on.. which looks not clean and not right.

What is the right way to be able to load this library as a whole and *everything inside*, or at least all `js` inside, into an `html` page ?

If I share this library, I don't want other devs to list and load each `js/css`.

Comment: It's exactly how other libraries do this, look at [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#download-cdn). The more modern approach would be to use npm and create a module out of your library

Comment: thanks, so basically if you make a game, and each character on this game has a library with many js files, we are going to have to add ALL js from all libs into the main html? the only other alternative is npm? I just want to organize my code that is going to have lots of independent moving elements.

Comment: You usually use modules. Use a bundler to bundle assets together. You can read about vite or webpack

Comment: thanks, but i can't re-create a module for every new line of code I am testing, I am surprised that it is so messy, I thought I just miss something about encapsulation, but if you have to bundle assests for every basic lib its kind of ugly :)

Comment: It's done automatically once you setup your configs. I don't know what's messy about that

Comment: thank you, messy because i have to use external tools to get a very basic functionality I can easily achieve using imports in Python for example.

Comment: You can use imports as well that's what is called modules, you don't have to bundle them, that's just more efficient. You just have to add `type="module"` to your script tag

Comment: thanks a lot, but yet again many problems with this, you can't test it locally due to CORS (then how exactly do you test your code? you deploy for every line?) you can't add css or html, or import the whole lib, this is very far from the normal import such as Python.

Comment: You have to use a development server to develop things. Usually live server in vscode or `npx serve` is enough

Comment: python modules and javascript modules are very similar, in practice.  You're comparing python to javascript plus html plus css plus http servers, so of course it's going to look more complicated: it's a lot more stuff.

Comment: @DanielBeck you are right , I guess I am not knowledgable about this enough. I am curious how up till now, they didn't improved the integrity of those 3 (css/html/js) as the most popular technology out there.

Comment: @gotiredofcoding your opinion is based on little knowledge, I think you need to do some front-end courses & tutorials

Comment: @BritishSam i guess i need, though I was a CTO of a large web company and I do this for 8 years. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to load CSS. Placing your script tag above the header section will load the CSS before your actual site.

Use a hosting like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) for some temporary CSS file hosting.

May not load the CSS fast but at the moment it's the solution I use for sharing my libraries.

```
<script>
         
        // Get HTML head element
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
 
        // Create new link Element
        var link = document.createElement('link');
 
        // set the attributes for link element
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
     
        link.type = 'text/css';
     
        link.href = 'INSERTYOURLINKHERE';
 
        // Append link element to HTML head
        head.appendChild(link);
    </script>
```